# LDAP Change base number for uID and gID

Tags: ldap

So, I want to use LDAP for some servers access and group sudo.

Problem: when creating users in LDAP the uids (and gids) start at 1000. How can i change that base number to 10000?

So when i add an user it would start at 10000 and going up with the next when creating new users.

Comment: I'm using phpldapadmin and found a way to do that by changing the config file.

but. using the rfc2307bis when i try to add the posixGroup object class to a groupOfNames object it doesn't autopopulate the gidNumber. 

But i guess it is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i solved it by modifying phpldamadmin code for both uid and gid.